# Request.File is Empty MVC 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, request

![enter image description here]I am creating an action to send email with rich text message and attachment. I need to save the attachment file to disc before sending the email.

My work environment:

- MVC 4.0,
- Bootstrap 3.0,
- Jasny-Bootstrap

My Get Action Method:

```
public ActionResult CreateCommunication()
{
  .... 
  return View(new EmailMessage()); 
}
```

My Form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="MyEmail/CreateCommunication" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  ...
</form>
```

My Post Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCommunication(FormCollection formCollection)
{
  var to = formCollection["To"];
  var from = formCollection["From"];
  var message = formCollection["Message"]

  var file = Request.Files[0];
  ...
  ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any clue?

I have also tried

```
public ActionResult CreateCommunication(FormCollection formCollection, HttpPostedFileBase fileinput)
{
}
```

for post action method where fileinput is the `<input type="file" name="fileinput" id="fileinput"/>` in my form but in the method fileinput is `null`

Please find bellow the RequestHeader which has the correct Content-Type, i.e.:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

[image: Request Header from FireFox]

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Check if you are getting only one file in Request.Files...

Comment: @unique There is no error message as the form was posted properly

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe in the Post Method when I use Request.Files.Count it  returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. As the form was inside a bootstrap modal window it was using the 
Ajax Submit Handler when I refer to the default Submit handler its working fine.

Note to remember is NEVER use ajax submit for file uploader.